# Reactjs, array index getting changed when i drop element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I'm creating table with items in the checkbox list, but when I choose and submit some items, the index of remaining items are getting changed, so I can't submit again the remaining items.

Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      allStudent: [
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'student1',
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'student2',
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          name: 'student3',
        },
      ],
      studentList: [],
      checked: [false, false, false],
    };
    this.handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    this.handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
    };

    this.updateCheck = this.updateCheck.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    let students = [];
    for (let idx in this.state.checked) {
      if (this.state.checked[idx] && students.indexOf(this.state.checked[idx]) === -1) {
        students.push(this.state.allStudent[idx]);
      }
    }
    console.log('students', students);
    this.setState({
      studentList: update(this.state.studentList, { $push: students }),
    });
  }

  updateCheck(e, isChecked, i) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('selected', i, isChecked);
    this.setState({
      checked: update(this.state.checked, { [i]: { $set: isChecked } }),
    });
  }

  render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton label="Cancel" primary={true} onClick={this.handleClose} />,
      <FlatButton label="Submit" primary={true} keyboardFocused={true} onClick={this.handleSubmit} />,
    ];

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', float: 'left' }}>
          <Card style={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <CardTitle title="Test" />
            <div style={{ float: 'left', width: '25%' }}>
              <div style={{ float: 'right', overflow: 'auto' }}>
                <RaisedButton label="+" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
              </div>
              <Dialog
                title="All students"
                actions={actions}
                modal={false}
                open={this.state.open}
                onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                autoScrollBodyContent={true}
              >
                <div>
                  {this.state.allStudent
                    .filter(student => {
                      return !(student.id in _.keyBy(this.state.studentList, 'id'));
                    })
                    .map(
                      function(allStudent, i) {
                        return (
                          <Checkbox
                            key={allStudent.name}
                            label={allStudent.name}
                            style={styles.block}
                            checked={this.state.checked[i]}
                            onCheck={(e, isChecked) => this.updateCheck(e, isChecked, i)}
                          />
                        );
                      }.bind(this),
                    )}
                </div>
              </Dialog>

              <Table selectable={false}>
                <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableHeaderColumn style={{ width: '15%' }}>StudentList</TableHeaderColumn>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
                  {this.state.studentList.map(
                    function(student, i) {
                      console.log('id=', student.id);
                      return (
                        <TableRow key={student.id}>
                          <TableRowColumn style={{ width: '10%' }}>{student.name}</TableRowColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                      );
                    }.bind(this),
                  )}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm having this error when I submit again, "flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key". Because the indexes of remaining items are getting changed, I think.

Comment: Is your student.id unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the index value of `.map()` as the key rather than *student.id*, as this may not be unique.

```
key={index}
```

In your case it should be,

```
<TableRow key={i}>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Checkbox
  key={allStudent.name}
  label={allStudent.name}
  style={styles.block}
  checked={this.state.checked[i]}
  onCheck={(e, isChecked) => this.updateCheck(e, isChecked, i)}
/>
```

```
<TableRow key={student.id}>
```

you are getting this warning because the **key** should be unique, try to make it unique as much as possible.

also take care you will find a lot of examples depending on the index, which is not best practice.

check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html/) for more information